# Running WSL2 on Windows 10 Enterprise to drive Docker Backend

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to have my Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC (IOT) on run WSL 2. I'm at the latest LTSC Version (1809, build 17763) and have WSL 1 enabled, however installing WSL 2 seems to be limited to the Version 1903 and above, which isn't available for the LTSC configuration. Has anyone got a workaround for LTSC builds to get WSL 2 installed?

I'd like to have Docker's WSL 2 backend running, which is a requirement for Laravel's Sail Environment

Comment: Can you please show us the dockerfile to get more info.

Comment: Builds lower than 18362 do not support WSL 2.